Ubuntu 22 on ThinkPad X13
I have cloned old laptop disk to new laptop (ThinkPad X11 Gen 5) Old laptop was ThinkPad E450 with Ubuntu 20.
After cloning I got new laptop working but with issues like no wireless, sound or touch pad not working hence upgraded to Ubuntu 22.
Still I issues like no sound,wireless network not visible, touch pad not working.
Can someone help ? I am not a techie guy

Can you try fresh installing either 22.04 or 24.04? Upgrades sometimes cause problems like this
